# get value from form input and save in to array 2D

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, input

I want to save my input values into a 2D array.

```
<table>
  <?php
    $kriteria = array('IP', 'SE', 'PE', 'BE');

  ?>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Kriteria</th>
        <?php
           foreach ($kriteria as $val) {
              echo '<th>' . $val . '</th>';
           }
        ?>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php $n = count($kriteria); ?>
      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++): ?>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <?= $kriteria[$i] ?>
        </th>
        <?php for ($j = 0; $j < $n; $j++): ?>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="<?= $kriteria[$j] . $kriteria[$i] ?>" name="<?= $j. $i ?>" value=""></td>
        <?php endfor; ?>
      </tr>
      <?php endfor; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried with the `POST` method but it didn't work.

I want to use the value from the input for counting in another page.

> this the result 
>   [image]

Comment: When you say _I tried with the `POST` method_ what exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use the value from the input for counting in another page.

```
public function page1()
{
    $kriteria = json_encode(array('IP', 'SE', 'PE', 'BE'));
    $temp = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/tmp_file_123';
    file_put_contents($temp, $kriteria);
}

public function page2()
{
    $temp = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/tmp_file_123';
    $kriteria = file_get_contents($temp);
}
```